# Text outside of table data

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can i add text outside of td in the table like the red lines that i have draw in the photo ?
Table markup is:

```
<table>
<thead>
 <tr><th class="span2"><div class="outside"></div></th>
     <th class="span2"></th>
     <th class="span2"></th>
     <th class="span2"></th>
     <th class="span2"></th>
     <th class="span2"></th>    
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="span2"></td>
    <td class="span2"></td>
    <td class="span2"></td>
    <td class="span2"></td>
    <td class="span2"></td>
    <td class="span2"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can i position absolutely outside ".outside" div which is inside td. It is working in Google Chrome but not in Firefox. I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

[image]

Comment: Do you actually want redlines or are you looking to add text in the column?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3abefore) pseudo-selector?

```
tr:before {
    content: "Text";
    font-size: 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dQCPz/)**

Comment: Hey very nice and clever!

Comment: It is nice solution, but i am using twitter bootstrap and i have created <td class="span2"></td>. I have 6 td and it takes all the width. I must add these line of text position:absolute;

Comment: Can you post your bootstrap code? Because it seems to work just fine for me with my method and bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/MgcDU/5652/

Comment: Now i'am going to edit with table with bootstrap classes :)

Comment: Still works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/MapkY/1/

Comment: I must add the text outside the content div, when i am adding :before it is inside the content.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the table inside a div and add this property to div:-

```
#divid
{
border:2px dashed #ff2200;
}
```

Initially i misunderstood your question , if you want vertical text check this out:-

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SMP6/)

Comment: He probably wants to add *text* where those red lines are. After all, it says so in the title.

Comment: @Madara Oh.. yes. Actually i looked at the picture and thought that he needs a border around a table :)

Comment: Yeah i need to add text on the red lines :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add an extra column "`<td>`" per row give it a specific class lets say "RowTitle" then in css remove the styles so it has no borders.

```
<table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>Title 1</th>
     <th>Title 2</th>
    <th>Title 3</th>
<th>Title 4</th>
     <th>Title 5</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="RowTitle">Title Text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody
```

Css:
.RowTitle {border:white solid 0px}

Comment: I can't use these type because table must be all the width of the content. These red lines must be outside of the content. Is there any possiblity to add these text in red lines absolutely ?

Answer (score 0):

Usual hack:

(sorry for bad ASCII)

```
_____Invisible table______
|  ___   _____________   |  
|  | |   |           |   |
|  | |   |           |   |
|  | |   |           |   |
|  | |   |           |   |
|  | |   |           |   |
|  | |   |           |   |
|  I_I   I___________I   |  
| red        ur table    |
|                        |
I________________________I
```

1) Create a

`<span class="right"> 
  Your given table
</span>`

And A table on the left side

`<table>` 
`<!-- empty rows -->   <tr><td></td></tr>`
`<!-- empty rows -->   <tr><td></td></tr>` 
`<tr><td><img src="red-line-links.jpg"></td></tr>` where you want to display red lines
`<!-- more empty rows -->   <tr><td></td></tr>` 
`</table>`

Stylesheet:
`.right{float:right;text-align:left;padding:5px 0 5px 5px;position:relative}`

2) 
Second way is to wrap in a big invisible table

`<table border=0> <!-- use css for borders etc, border=0 is only for illustration -->`
`<tr>`
`<td>`
`<table id="first-table-with-red-lines">`
`...</table>`
`</td>`
`<td> <!-- your existing table -->`
`</td>`
`</tr>`
`</table>`

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing, I added a delete button to the left of the table, but it had to be part of the table as it was dynamically generated for each row. I used **position:absolute** on what was to be generated on or inside the targeted . I just added the class to the last `, and positioned it. It worked great. Here's some of my code:

**CSS**

```
 `.deleteBtn {
  height: 76px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`
```